# Extraer última palabra de una lista de strings

Tags: python, string, lista

Quiero extraer el país de una lista cuyo principal contenido viene de la siguiente manera:

```
 ['LC-39A, Kennedy Space Center, Florida, USA'  
'Site 9401 (SLS-2), Jiuquan Satellite Launch Center, China'  
'Pad A, Boca Chica, Texas, USA',   
'Site 200/39, Baikonur Cosmodrome, Kazakhstan']
```

Mi objetivo es extraer los países, es decir lo siguiente a una lista externa:

```
[USA, China, USA, Kazakhstan]
```

He probado con:

```
.str.contains(",\s.*$")
```

para extraer el final de cada string de la lista, sin embargo me saca la información entera cuando lo que busco es simplemente los países, nada más.

No sé cómo debo filtrar o cómo puedo llegar a la última palabra de la string para extraerla posteriormente.

Comment: `[ e.split(", ")[-1] for e in tu_lista ]`

Comment: Pero las listas con tienen disponible el comando .split

Comment: Si me puede explicar mejor que quiere indicar, soy nuevo y no entiendo muy bien... Gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
[e.split(", ")[-1] for e in tu_lista]
```

De lo que se trata es de:

- Iterar sobre cada elemento de tu lista. Cada elemento es una cadena, como por ejemplo `"Pad A, Boca Chica, Texas, USA"`
- Usar la función `.split(", ")` para que esa cadena quede dividida en "trozos", usando como separador la coma seguida de espacio. El resultado será una lista con cada uno de los trozos. En el ejemplo sería `["Pad A", "Boca Chica", "Texas", "USA"]`.
- Quedarse con el último elemento de la lista resultante del split. El último elemento tiene índice `[-1]`
- Añadir ese elemento a otra lista que vamos construyendo

Al terminar la iteración anterior tendremos otra lista con sólo los nombres de los países.

Ahora pasemos esa idea a código python. Podemos hacer un bucle `for` "normal":

```
lista = [
  'LC-39A, Kennedy Space Center, Florida, USA',
  'Site 9401 (SLS-2), Jiuquan Satellite Launch Center, China',
  'Pad A, Boca Chica, Texas, USA',
  'Site 200/39, Baikonur Cosmodrome, Kazakhstan'
]
paises = []
for elemento in lista:
  troceado = elemento.split(", ")
  pais = troceado[-1]
  paises.append(pais)
```

O podemos usar una *list comprehension* que permite abreviar todo lo anterior en una sola línea:

```
paises = [ elemento.split(", ")[-1] for elemento in lista ]
```

En ambos casos el resultado en la variable `paises` será:

```
['USA', 'China', 'USA', 'Kazakhstan']
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Era más simple de lo que pensaba, muy amable!!

Comment: @Ersanto Si la respuesta proporcionada solventa el problema que tenías, puedes marcarla como válida [https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas].